# Pandas Logistic Regression mixed type not supported?

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression

I'm working on making a logistic regression with a simple dataset in Python:
[image: Simple dataset with 5 rows]

My goal is to predict whether or not someone survived.
After cleaning the dataset & getting rid of *NaN* values as well as *String* columns, I've used the following code to turn every column data type to *float64*(cleaned dataset shown below as well):
[image: Dataset cleaned and values turned to float64]

```
titanic_data['Survived'] = titanic_data['Survived'].astype(float)
titanic_data['Sibling/Spouse'] = titanic_data['Sibling/Spouse'].astype(float)
titanic_data['Parents/Children'] = titanic_data['Parents/Children'].astype(float)
titanic_data['male'] = titanic_data['male'].astype(float)
titanic_data['Q'] = titanic_data['Q'].astype(float)
titanic_data['S'] = titanic_data['S'].astype(float)
titanic_data[2] = titanic_data[2].astype(float)
titanic_data[3] = titanic_data[3].astype(float)
```

Output of the above code:

```
Survived            float64
Age                 float64
Sibling/Spouse      float64
Parents/Children    float64
Fare                float64
male                float64
Q                   float64
S                   float64
2                   float64
3                   float64
dtype: object
```

When I run my Logistic Regression code(shown below), I get the error **mixed type of string and non-string is not supported**.

My Regression code:

```
# Logistic regression
# Split the dataset

x = titanic_data.drop("Survived",axis=1)
y = titanic_data["Survived"]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=1)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

But as you can see, I've changed my column data types to all be the same, so why am I getting this error & what can I do to fix it?

EDIT: The error message I got:
[image: Error message]

Comment: Can you include the complete error message for better context?

Comment: Sure. I'll edit the question to add that.

Comment: How do you create `titanic_data[2]` and `titanic_data[3]`?

Comment: I used the line passenger_class = pd.get_dummies(titanic_data["Passenger_class"],drop_first = True) line to add someone's passenger class as a binary variable, since if both are false, the class would be 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing is not about the column content, but about column names. **Beware of naming columns with non-strings** (e.g. 0/1/2/3 for quantile markers or one-hot-encoded levels). Sklearn's [sanity checks](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/utils/validation.py#L1998) expect that *column names are strings*. For safety, try

```py
X.columns = X.columns.astype(str)
```

To avoid such problems (rather than fixing afterwards), use more canonical ways to manipulate and encode data, like `pd.get_dummies` or others. Here is a fully working example:

```py
# Fetch Titanic

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
X, y = fetch_openml("titanic", version=1, as_frame=True, return_X_y=True,)
dropped_cols = ['boat', 'body', 'home.dest', 'name', 'cabin', 'embarked', 'ticket']
X.drop(dropped_cols, axis=1, inplace=True)

# Encode (one-hot for categories) & inpute (naive)

import pandas as pd
X = pd.get_dummies(X,columns=['sex', 'pclass'], drop_first=True)
y = y.astype(float)
X = X.fillna(0)

# Logistic regression

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X, y)
logreg.score(X,y) # 0.7868601986249045
```

Here `get_dummies` method did one-hot-encoding naming columns with prefixes, hence maintaining the proper string type. `X.columns` looks as below:

```
Index(['age', 'sibsp', 'parch', 'fare', 'sex_male', 'pclass_2.0',
       'pclass_3.0'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: OK. Could I also use something like titanic_data.rename(columns={2:'2',3: '3'}, inplace=True) to change the names of those last two columns?

Comment: Problematic integer-named columns were indeed created by unfortunate one-hot encoding and can be fixed after, for instance as you proposed. However, my advice is to avoid these problems altogether by using dedicated methods for encoding. See my updated answer.

Comment: OK, so looking at your example, I think you basically used get_dummies on the _sex_ and _pclass_ columns, then because you had stored the dataset into both **X** and **y**, you then changed the type of everything in **y** to _float_, filled all the _na_ values with _0_, and then ran the logistic regression. 
Is that right?

Comment: Indeed, I used `pd.get_dummies` to handle categoricals properly (note that it has other options such as drop-first etc), and took care of `y`'s type too.

Comment: I am glad that I could help.
PS: But zero-filling by assignment is not a good practice,  and I typically use imputers :-)

Comment: Noted! I will keep that in mind.